# SQL Server : how to search for text that has a commas at the beginning of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a column `Animal` in my table with data like this:

```
dog 2, cat 3, bird 2
,dog 2
,cat 4
```

I want to find row2 with `,` at the beginning of the string.

For example, `Animal like ',dog 2'`

Comment: Why row 2 and not row 3?

Comment: you can look for `LEFT(Animal, 1) = ','`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LIKE` operator like

```
Animal like ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Animal like ',dog%'
```

If you want specific numbers in the search then you can use Regular Expression